# react-native Expo FileSystem.downloadAsync respond 400 bad request on ios but on android got 200

Tags: react-native, expo

my problem is i had 400 bad request when i try to download a file using expo filesystem.downloadAsync on ios devise.

```
const shareDocument = async (event) => {
const data = JSON.parse(event.nativeEvent.data);
const documentName = data.documentName.replace(/[^a-z0-9.]/gi,'_');
const file = await FileSystem.downloadAsync(
    config.API_DOC_URI + "/documents/pdf/download/" + data.documentId,
    FileSystem.cacheDirectory + documentName,
    {
        headers : {
          'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Authorization': "Bearer " + data.jwt,
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': data.csrf,
        }
    }
)
// sharing interface
try {
    if (await Sharing.isAvailableAsync()) {
        await Sharing.shareAsync(file.uri, {UTI:"com.adobe.pdf", mimeType:"application/pdf"});
    }
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

anyone has an idea how can i fix this issue.

random behavior: NOT ALL IOS DEVISES HAVE THIS PROBLEM.

Comment: Did you request permission for Device Storage access before you save data on device on iOS?

Comment: @FistonEmmanuel yes all god forgot to mention thet on my local environment works fine but on others environment don't besides it's so random some phone got 400 bad request other no. i am not sure but i was focusing on the request header i think it's cookies problem. got no way to see how my request created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(fileUri, report.data, { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,});`
where fileUri is destination url (device specific) and report.data is files url. I don't know in what format your pdf is, mine was buffer array, I ended up converting it to base64, so report.data was base64 string